# Writing Reducer using typescript. How can I correct the error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, types, typesafe-actions

I use typescript, react, redux, typessafe-actions.

I have this error.

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(...items: ConcatArray[]): List[]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '{ id: number; name: string | undefined; email: string | undefined; gender: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConcatArray'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'ConcatArray'.ts(2769)

This is error code.

```
id: Math.max(...state.map((todo) => todo.id)) + 1,
```

I modified the id type to correct the error, but the error cannot be solved. How should I fix it?

```
// <Types.d.ts>
    export interface PersonType {
      id?: number;
      name?: string;
      email?: string;
      gender?: string;
    }
```

```
// <PeopleReducers.ts>

    import { ActionType, createAction, createReducer } from "typesafe-actions";
    import { PersonType } from "../../types";
    
    export const ADD_LIST = "people/ADD_LIST";
    export const DELETE_LIST = "people/DELETE_LIST";
    
    export const addList = createAction(
      ADD_LIST,
      ({ id, name, email, gender }: PersonType) => ({
        id,
        name,
        email,
        gender,
      })
    )();
    export const deleteList = createAction(DELETE_LIST, ({ id }) => ({
      id,
    }))();
    
    const actions = { addList, deleteList };
    type ListAction = ActionType<typeof actions>;
    
    export type List = {
      id: number;
      name: string;
      email: string;
      gender: string;
    };
    type ListState = List[];
    
    const initialState: ListState = [];
    
    const list = createReducer<ListState, ListAction>(initialState, {
      [ADD_LIST]: (state, { payload: { name, email, gender } }) =>
        state.concat({
          id: Math.max(...state.map((todo) => todo.id)) + 1, // This is error line
          name,
          email,
          gender,
        }),
      [DELETE_LIST]: (state, { payload: { id } }) =>
        state.filter((item) => item.id !== id),
    });
    export default list;
```

```
//  <Row component>


    import { PersonType } from "../types";
    
    export default function Row({ name, email, gender }: PersonType) {
      return (
        <>
          <p>{name}</p>
          <p>{email}</p>
          <p>{gender}</p>
        </>
      );
    }
```

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use id without error. When I run the ADD_LIST action, I want to add id, name, email, and gender to the LIST array(state).

Comment: yeah, but what do you wanna achieve from this `Math.max(...state.map((todo) => todo.id)) + 1` exactly?

Comment: Oh, I'm just trying to add a unique id. There are 100 mockdata, but I'd like to add 101 and 102.

Comment: did you try spreading instead?: 
` [ADD_LIST]: (state, { payload: { name, email, gender } }) =>
        [...state,{
          id: Math.max(...state.map((todo) => todo.id)) + 1,
          name,
          email,
          gender,
        }],`

Comment: I'll try that, too. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: Please also note that there is the official "redux toolkit" library that also deals with TypeScript in a large way. Nowadays there is no real reason to go for third-party libraries like typesafe-actions if you are not training to work on a project that uses these for historical reasons.
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem: Possibly Undefined Properties

The error is confusingly worded, but the issue is that the properties `name`, `email`, and `gender` are defined as optional in the payload from the action creator (`PersonType`).  When you `concat` an item to the state `List[]` it **must** be a complete `List` object.  So these optional properties are a problem.

#### Bad Solution: Set Defaults

You can prevent errors by defaulting all of the `payload` properties to an empty string.

```
[ADD_LIST]: (state, { payload: { name = "", email = "", gender = "" } }) =>
  state.concat({
    id: Math.max(...state.map((todo) => todo.id)) + 1,
    name,
    email,
    gender
  }),
```

#### Good Solution: Fix the Action

It is always better to tackle the problem as the source.  Why are we allowing these required properties to be optional in the action creator?  We want to require all properties except that we don't want an `id` because we are going to create that ourselves.

```
export const addList = createAction(
  ADD_LIST,
  ({ name, email, gender }: Omit<List, "id">) => ({
    name,
    email,
    gender
  })
)();
```

or simply:

```
export const addList = createAction(
  ADD_LIST,
  (payload: Omit<List, "id">) => payload
)();
```

Now your reducer can stay the same as it was before.  The errors will be gone because the required properties are known to be present in the action `payload`.

Comment: It was my first time using Typescript and Redux, so I was very confused, but I knew I didn't know it. Thank you so much!!